# Using 'ps' command in Linux, how to see the realtime data?

Tags: java, linux, cpu, ps

I found that my java web server(tomcat) used high cpu, so I used 'ps aux' to see the process infomation, like:

```
# ps aux  | grep -E "PID|java"
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    
root      7533  143 39.8
```

It showed that java took 143% cpu.
Then I used 'top' command to see, the cpu usage of java process was also about 140%.

After that, I took the web server offline(no access, bug process still living).
Then I used top to see, java used very low cpu:

```
# top | grep -E "PID|java"       
PID %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND 
7533  0.7 39.9 455:13.81 java   
PID %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
```

'vmstat' also showed that the cpu was almost idle:

```
# vmstat 1
-----cpu------
us sy id wa st
 19  1 79  1  0
 0  0 99  1  0
 0  0 100  0  0
 0  0 100  0  0
 0  0 98  1  0
 0  0 99  1  0
```

Then, I used 'ps' command again, the result was:

```
#ps aux  | grep -E "PID|java"
USER       PID %CPU %MEM  
root      7533  137 39.8
```

It showed that 7533 still takes 137% cpu! After a long time, I check 'ps' again, the result is still %137...

So, dose the 'ps' command show some old data? And how can I see the realtime data by 'ps'(Because I want to use 'ps -L' to see the information of thread)? Or is that just impossible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there are many tools to see the `almost` real time process state, like:
`top`
`htop`
`dstat`

Also, in linux, you can explore system state, including `cpu information`, `process information`, `network and interface information` and so fourth under `/proc` folder.
This is where all the data that tools extract from.

Comment: Hello, Thank you! I want see not only process state, but also thread state, like the result of 'ps -eL'. Which tool can do this?

Comment: @lonelycoder  my favorite tool is `htop`, you can do some setup in `htop` to make it display `thread` information!